# SVN (Tortoise) No longer detects newly added files on commit (auto ignored)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**Problem:** As of recently, If I add a new file to a checked out repository, the added file defaults to ignored and does not show in the list of files during commit.

**Reproduce:** 1) Create a new file in a checked out folder. 2) The icon overly for the file is that of 'ignore' 3) Commit 4) The added file does not show in the list of files to commit

**Troubleshooting:** I suspect I've accidentally set a global or project ignore setting but I can't find it.

(Here is my global ignore list)

```
*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store Thumbs.db .vs Outputx86 x86 Debug Release obj bin *.user *.DotSettings *.cache new.lzip VERSION Output *.suo *cache *.mybackup *-cache *-SetupFiles
```

*(I've done quite a bit of searching before asking this question but couldn't find an answer that suited.)*

**Edit:** 
I've verified that it is only against this checkout...but I can't seem to find anything amiss in ignore under the svn-properties for the folder. I even tried removind the ignore field of the properties, to no avail.

**Solved:** Thanks to Gene for the help. It turns out that someone had accidentally did a recursive ignore on the main checkout folder. There was an entry, " .vs * ", with a space between the two that was very hard to find. To see the ignore properties for a folder, right click on the folder and select SVN=>Properties. Note that ignore properties are inherited from global ignore settings, and parent folders.

Comment: FWIW: Coming to SVNTortoise (for one client) from previously using GIT, I didn't at first realize I had to check "Show unversioned files" in the Commit dialog. Otherwise, new ".cs" files were not in the list of files to commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN combines your global ignore list with the ignore list in the current directory and checked out directories above.  Is it possible that one of these directories ignores the files you are trying to add?

Look especially for a space in the wrong place, for example between the * and .o in *.o

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've verified that the problem exists at the top directory. When I look at its properties there is nothing in ignore that is suspect. However, I guess that a good test would be to try another checked out folder to see if the problem is global or local.

Comment: Thanks again Gene, it turns out you were right. Somebody had accidentally did a recursive ignore on the source folder. It was hard to see but the problem was in the space between items. For those reading in the future, right click on the folder, chose SVN=>Properties, and look very carefully at the ignore list. I happened to have a " .vs * " in there . It was really easy to miss the space between the .vs and the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happen when you add ***.vs** or *. or * files or hidden folders in ignore list (Recursively), You may resolve by following 6 steps as showing in picture below. hope this will help

[image]